# WordPress check empty data in a query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am displaying some data from wp_share table using a `foreach loop`. What I am trying if there is no-data then it will show a msg like "there is no data found" and if found then it will go to the loop.

Following code I have written but it is always getting the empty value, though there is data actually.

```
<?php 

   $me=$current_user->user_login;
   $retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_share where Status='onsell' and user!='$me'" );
   echo '<table border=0 class="table">
   <tr> <th colspan="5" style="color:blue;border-bottom:2px solid blue;"> Purchase share from user offer</th> </tr>

   <tr><th>OfferBy</th><th>OfferValue</th><th>Qnty</th> <th> ref</th> <th> action</th></tr>';


     if (mysql_num_rows($retrieve_data)<=0) {
     echo '<tr><td style="color:crimson;">'  ."there is no data found". '</td>';
     }

    else{
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){

    echo '<tr><td>'. $retrieved_data->user.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'.$retrieved_data->offervalue.'</td>';

    echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->user.'</td>';
    echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->id.'</td>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: hi I apologize actually I am trying to approve your changes but not finding any option how to do that thnks.

Comment: It's done already, you can see [the revision history here](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46314128/revisions). Community members having more than 2,000 reputation points have edits approved automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code there are many error available . `mysql_num_rows` is not used in WordPress. In WordPress to check number of row in result used `$wpdb->num_rows`

Try below code it help you

```
<?php 
global $wpdb;
$me=$current_user->user_login;
$retrieve_data = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM wp_share where Status='onsell' and user!='".$me."'" );
echo '<table border=0 class="table">
<tr> <th colspan="5" style="color:blue;border-bottom:2px solid blue;"> Purchase share from user offer</th> </tr><tr><th>OfferBy</th><th>OfferValue</th><th>Qnty</th> <th> ref</th> <th> action</th></tr>';


if ($wpdb->num_rows<=0) {
    echo '<tr><td style="color:crimson;">'  ."there is no data found". '</td>';
}else{
    foreach ($retrieve_data as $retrieved_data){

        echo '<tr><td>'. $retrieved_data->user.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'.$retrieved_data->offervalue.'</td>';

        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->user.'</td>';
        echo '<td>'. $retrieved_data->id.'</td></tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @Mithu My answer is helpful or not ?

Comment: hi gr8 its working. actually i was busy with my code.  thanks for help